# ListView cannot load delegate from another qml file

Tags: qt, listview, delegates, qml

i want to use `ListViewDelegate.qml` as a delegate for my list view items on my `Kos.qml`. but it giving me this error. i also try using loader but it seems didn't work, i try to remove the curly braces and it load the Kos.qml page but it didn't render the list view

```
file:/ngomahyukv2/Kos.qml:55: ListViewDelegate is not a type
File name case mismatch
```

@Kos.qml
i use another file `PageBackground.qml` as a background

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

PageBackground {
    id: kos
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Text {
        id: element
        x: 6
        y: 20
        width: 24
        height: 32
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: qsTr("<")
        font.strikeout: false
        styleColor: "#ffffff"
        font.underline: false
        font.italic: false
        font.bold: true
        font.pixelSize: 25
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: kosloader.source = ""
        }

    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        x: 0
        y: 69
        width: 640
        height: 410
        model: ListModel{
//            need to be in for loop and data from database
           ListElement{
                imagePath : "static/Bisnis-kos-kosan.png"
                kosName : "Kos Name"
                kosAlamat : "Jalan Lorem"
                kosJumlahKamar: "5"
                kosGender : "Laki-laki"
                kosHarga: "7000000"
                kosProfile: "KosSpec.qml"
                ownerContact: "instgram.com"
            }
        }

        delegate: ListViewDelegate { }
   }

    Loader{
        id: kosspec
        visible: false
        source: ""
    }
}
```

@ListViewDelegate.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

Item {
    id: listviewdelegate
    Image {
        id: idthumbnail
        x: 8
        y: 8
        width: 227
        height: 158
        source: imagePath
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
    }

    Text {
        id: idnamakos
        x: 252
        y: 8
        text: kosName
        font.bold: true
        font.family: "Verdana"
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        font.pixelSize: 22
    }

    Text {
        id: idalamat
        x: 251
        y: 40
        width: 301
        height: 17
        text: qsTr("Alamat            : " + kosAlamat)
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        font.pixelSize: 12
        font.family: "Verdana"
    }

    Text {
        id: idjumlahkamar
        x: 252
        y: 63
        width: 240
        height: 14
        text: qsTr("Jumlah Kamar : " + kosJumlahKamar)
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        font.pixelSize: 12
        font.family: "Verdana"
    }

    Text {
        id: idgender
        x: 251
        y: 83
        width: 265
        height: 14
        text: qsTr("Gender            : " + kosGender)
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        font.pixelSize: 12
        font.family: "Verdana"
    }

    Text {
        id: idharga
        x: 251
        y: 103
        width: 373
        height: 14
        text: qsTr("Harga              : " + kosHarga)
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        font.pixelSize: 12
        elide: Text.ElideNone
        font.family: "Verdana"
    }

    Button {
        id: buttonCek
        x: 510
        y: 131
        width: 96
        height: 35
        visible: true
        font.family: "Verdana"
        font.pixelSize: 16
        background: Rectangle{
            color: "#ef3644"
            anchors.fill: parent

        }
        contentItem: Text {
            id: cek
            text: "CEK"
            anchors.fill: parent
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 10
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            color: "#ffffff"
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseAreaCek
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                kosspec.visible = true
                kosspec.source = kosProfile
            }
        }


    }

    Button {
        id: buttonHubungi
        x: 400
        y: 131
        width: 96
        height: 35
        font.family: "Verdana"
        visible: true
        contentItem: Text {
            id: name1
            color: "#ef3644"
            text: "HUBUNGI"
            anchors.fill: parent
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 10
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "#00f1f0f0"
            border.width: 4
            border.color: "#ef3644"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
        font.pixelSize: 16

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseAreaHubungi
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                Qt.openUrlExternally (ownerContact);
            }
        }
    }

    ToolSeparator {
        id: toolSeparator
        x: 5
        y: 172
        width: 600
        height: 15
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file name casing is actually what it should be? (First letter capital for qml filenames)

Comment: yes, i named the file "ListViewDelegate.qml"

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, it seems to have to do with the casing of your file. Custom types need to begin with a capital letter, but also check that you have got the `V` and `D` in the correct case.

Also, is the file in the same directory? Do you have files named the same but with different casing in parallel? Directories?

I'm pretty confident that the issue is in the file name, or the name of a file that interferes with the file name. However, if you want to create a type module and refer to the file that way, you can also poke at using `qmldir` files: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html .

But try to find something odd in your files first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure i named the file first letter capital. and yes it's in the same directory. i did try to make a new file with the same content. it didn't give me an error but fail to render the display